# complemented subspaces of $L_{p}$ spaces (Question posed incorrectly earlier)

Tags: banach-spaces

This question was asked incorrectly originally in such a way that it probably made no sense.  Fixed version:

I know that $L_{p}[0,1]$ has $\ell_{2}$ as a complemented subspace, and I'm wondering if this can be generalized to include $\ell_{q}$ for other values of $q\neq 2$.

However, the only natural way I can think of to embed the space is by taking coefficients of sequences in $\ell_{p}$ and using them as coefficients of the standard Haar Schauder basis of $L_{p}$.  To guarantee that the map is well-defined, I can use the usual trick of multiply by increasing powers of $2^{-1}$.

To clarify the map:  For $x\in\ell_{p}$, take $T(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}x_{n}f_{n}$, where $f_{n}$ is taken to be any normalized Schauder basis of $L_{p}[0,1]$.

I'm sure that this can't be correct though, as any textbook I've read usually devotes heavy theorem crunching (including Khintchine's inequality) just to verify the initial comment.

Comment: See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=complemented+subspaces+of+Lp+spaces&source=bl&ots=4drXD5LyUy&sig=Pz9mdlzFarRrC62_qnsVfJrsJPY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S6CHT5DND4qR8AGWpoDeCQ&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=complemented%20subspaces%20of%20Lp%20spaces&f=false) (In particular, Theorem 4.56 on page 215.)

Comment: Thanks very much.  I will take a look at this.  I now realize that I am skipping over the important additional requirement of being complemented in my argument, which is why it at first seemed to prove things that simply weren't true.

Comment: This is also Theorem 6.4.21 in Albiac and Kalton's *Topics in Banach Space Theory*. (For $1<p,q<\infty$, $\ell_q$ embeds complementably in $L_p$ if and only if $q=p$ or $q=2$).

Comment: This may be of interest. From Albiac/Kalton, Theorem 6.4.19: 1) For $1\le p\le 2$, $\ell_q$ embeds in $L_p$ iff $p\le q\le 2$. 2) For $2<p<\infty$, $\ell_q$ embeds in $L_p$ iff $q=2$ or $q=p$. Moreover, if $\ell_q$ embeds in $L_p$ then it embeds isometrically.